# Google Play Inapp Billing v3: what is the purpose of Backend Server?

Tags: java, android, in-app-billing, google-cloud-pubsub, android-billing

I have an Android app with inapp subscriptions (with a 7 day free trial period) and I am trying to upgrade it to Google Play Inapp Billing v3 following these instructions:

https://github.com/android/play-billing-samples/tree/master/ClassyTaxiJava

I don't understand what is the purpose of the "Backend Server". What is it for ?

By the way, if you have any link to a detailed tutorial to deploy such a server (Google explanations given [here](https://github.com/android/play-billing-samples/tree/master/ClassyTaxiServer) are quite 'light'), I am interested :)

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Main purpose of backend server is to act as an interface between mobile app and google play console. All this subscription lifecycle handling is done on server side and also dependig on this life cycle, RTDN are sent from server side to the mobile app. Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

The` backend server that is mentioned in your link a server that needs that library to work, but it does not mean that to implement in-app subscriptions and purchases in your app you need a backend server nor that github library.

Comment: Thanks but I still don't understand the purpose of this backend server project. What is it for ?

Comment: Main purpose of backend server is to act as an interface between mobile app and google play console. All this subscription lifecycle handling is done on server side and also dependig on this life cycle, RTDN are sent from server side to the mobile app. Hope this answers your question @Regis_AG